# Can I compare letter size (width and height in pixels)?

Tags: javascript

For example:

- G is wider than I
- W is wider than l(L)

How can I compare two letters' sizes in JS with a reasonable performance for testing an array with 5 000 elements.

Comment: Can you create an hidden dom element?

Comment: @Mr.Bruno No. I need find longest **size** (not length) string in array with 5k+ elements.

Comment: The fastest method is (I know you want avoid it) render text temporaly in canvas and use  Canvas.measureText method for each character of your font, store values in a key-value object and then use this object to calculate string width in array.

Comment: They way I see it, there is no proper way to do this other than to define yourself the width of every possible character beforehand in an object (`{'a':6, ..., 'i':1, ...}`) and run a function which adds the width of every char of your String together.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I same think about this solution + web worker for performance

Comment: Why do you have a requirement to do this '**without** inserting in DOM or render on canvas'? Seems like an unusual requirement for me.

Comment: @Zenoo yes, it is boring solution, but maybe better way :)

Comment: @xfix  I search faster solution because I have 5k+ elements.

Comment: @Zenoo answer is probably the fastest solution you can get. Measure every character once with your font, store it in an object and you never have to use DOM or canvas

Comment: Do you need to get the actual widths of the font that is currently "live" in someone else's browser, or is it close enough if you have the widths for *your* local font and size? If the latter, don't bother measuring it inside a web page. Do this just once and store the results in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on the front your page is using,[Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) has the same width, and Proportional Font is not, different Font Type is not same

Comment: I didn't mean to change your font, I mean the letter width is a feature of font, not webpage, you can't get the width from js or css(unless there is a model can store all letter width for all font type ,then check the font you use, and then return the size), It's just related to font you're using。

Answer (score 1):

Canvas solution, if you want to:

Edit: tried width both uppercase and lowercase, it works.

```js
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
    // re-use canvas object for better performance
    var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = font;
    var metrics = context.measureText(text);
    return metrics.width;
}

var letters = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]; // All character needed, upper and lowercase


var lettersWidth = $.map(letters,
function(letter, i){
    return { letter: letter,
             width:   getTextWidth(letter, "bold 12pt arial")}
});

console.log(lettersWidth);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### DOM Solution

```
<span id="ruler" style="visibility: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"></span>
```

Insert it in `body` element. Then use a function to measure the letter.

```
function measureLetter(letter) {
  const ruler = document.getElementById("ruler");
  ruler.innerHTML = letter;
  return ruler.offsetWidth;
}
```

This solution is based on putting the letter inside an element, and getting element's width with `offsetWidth`. For a fast solution i would do this once for every character and store its length in an object. Then the object can be used for comparing elements in your array, without using DOM or canvas.

For the function to return useful information, style your `span` element with a `font-family` and `font-size` of your choice.

Comment: It seems to retrieve rounded width based on CSS font-size (ES: 12)

Comment: You get rounded values anyway es: [font-size: 12px, font-family: arial] -> { A: 12, I: 5 }

Comment: @TomaszBubała Thank you for you answer, but i have implemented this solution, canvas better.